# No such property for variable in groovy script for janusgraph

Tags: groovy, gremlin, janusgraph

So I was test groovy in janusgraph(I want to load csv dataset in in-memory server) and i don't understand, why you can see variables in scirpt? How I need to create variable so I can use it in groovy and in gremlin console after scipt is loaded?
My test.groovy is just

```
def test = "aaaaa"
println test
```

and after I load test.groovy I got this error:

```
gremlin> :load databases/test.groovy
==>aaaaa
No such property: test for class: groovysh_evaluate
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: test for class: groovysh_evaluate
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Evaluator$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:201)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.commands.LoadCommand$_load_closure1.doCall(LoadCommand.groovy:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForLine(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:5969)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.eachLine(IOGroovyMethods.java:457)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.eachLine(IOGroovyMethods.java:410)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachLine(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:317)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachLine(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:301)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$998.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.commands.LoadCommand.load(LoadCommand.groovy:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.commands.LoadCommand$load.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.commands.LoadCommand.execute(LoadCommand.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Command$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:276)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:169)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:97)
    at java_lang_Runnable$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:265)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:524)
gremlin>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `def` and terminate the lines with `;[]` which will stop console echo.

```
test = 'aaaaaa';[]
println test;[]
```

then loading it

```
gremlin> :load test

aaaaaa
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but just remove "def" help me. I dont know why I used def anyway